# Why is my location constantly changing, is my code incorrect?

Tags: android, locationlistener, android-maps-v2

I am working toward building a distance traveled part of my application but I am having issues with my location. In the location listener I am outputting the Lat and Long coordinates in a toast and I can see the coordinates constantly changing, now I know they will never be perfectly the same each time but when I store the first registered location in the listener and then check the distance between that and the constantly updated location the distance jumps around and can be as high as 25 meters. Here is my listener code:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(flag ==0){

            locationC = location;
            flag = 1;
        }

        //Constantly updated location
        locationD = location;

        //walking distance is distance from first initialized location to current location
        walking = locationC.distanceTo(locationD);

        String s =String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()); 
        String ss =String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()); 

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  "+s+" "+ss+" " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Walking distance is "+walking ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }
}
```

here is the rest of my location code which is run in the onCreate method:

```
// Creating the location manger and towers etc
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);


    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE, MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,  new MyLocationListener());

    if (location != null) {
        glat = location.getLatitude();
        glon = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

I researched the V2 maps which I am using to see if there was a more accurate way to get the location and I found that `googleMap.getLocation();` was broken, and indeed it caused my application to fail. I am not sure if I have set up my listener correctly, or any of the other location code, I feel that the location should not be jumping around like that.

I will say that I am using GPS to get the location under a moderately cloudy sky, the device tells me location is set by GPS. Can anyone advise on a better pragmatically way to get a finer location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which is the value of your constant MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE?

I've assigned 50 meters to it and it's ok for [my app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=tureame). I also assigned 2 minutes to MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE.

[Source code of my app](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/tourGuide/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nbempire/android/tourguide/component/activity/MapActivity.java) | See method *subscribeToLocationUpdates*

Comment: Mine was set to 1, i will change it to 50 and see what the difference is thanks!!!

Comment: Your code helped me tune the location a bit more so thanks, but I have to admit my idea will not be successful with regards to calculating the distance someone walks, it just wont work. :(

Answer (score 3):

With the current GPS technology it's absolutely normal for lat/lon to jump around within a 20-50 meters.

Answer (score 3):

25m deviation is totally normal under *civilian* GPS precision.

See [here](http://earthmeasurement.com/GPS_accuracy.html) for more details about how GPS works, specially:

> The cause for poor accuracy is not always obvious but is usually
>   attributable to one of the following source of error:
>
> ```
> - Multipath / signal corruption
> - Low number of satellites / poor satellite geometry
> - Erratic Ionospheric activity
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you think then that this will not work with regards to counting distance traveled in meters? I want to somehow store the distance walked by a user and this was the only way I could see how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: if you know the maximum speed (walking people don't usually exceed 5km/hour) you may average your results to get more precise position. I'd average over 5-6 consecutive samples (or maybe 10 or more), because the walking people would not get far in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you I will try and figure something like this out, cheers!!